# how we disable dates of calendar from javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a calendar and in this i want to disable dates for example i want to disable dates 25 to 29

from javascript

Comment: Do this, and that. Or for detailed answer, post some code

Comment: i have dates array in javascript. and i want to disable these dates from javascript or jquery

Comment: that still really doesn't tell us anything. In isolation its almost meaningless.

Comment: i just want to know that how disable dates of calender

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [beforeShowDay](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#events) event to disable specific days:

```
$("selector").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        return [day < 25 || day > 29];
    }
});
```